# why would std::equal_to cause dynamic allocation?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, std-pair

Consider the following simple example, where I am using `std::equal_to` to compare two `std::pair<std::string, unsigned>`. The `operator new` is overloaded so that it prints a message when allocations take place (live code [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D97ZoqDURJufhPrc)):

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// overloaded to see when heap allocations take place
void* operator new(std::size_t n)
{
    std::cout << "Allocating " << n << std::endl;
    return malloc(n);
}

int main()
{
    using key_type = std::pair<std::string, unsigned>;
    auto key1 = std::make_pair(std::string("a_______long______string______"), 1);
    auto key2 = std::make_pair(std::string("a_______long______string______"), 1);

    std::cout << "Finished initial allocations\n\n" << std::endl;

    std::equal_to<key_type> eq;
    eq(key1, key2); // how can this cause dynamic allocation???
}
```

The message I am seeing is

```
Allocating 31
Allocating 31
Finished initial allocations


Allocating 31
Allocating 31
```

You can see there are two allocations taking place when comparing `key1` and `key2`. But why? `std::equal_to`'s operator takes its arguments by const reference so no allocation should take place... what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: Build flags/compiler command line?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont gcc 8.2.0 using c++17 with O2 optimisation

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is because you make copies of the pairs.

The types of `keyX` are `std::pair<std::string, int>`. `eq` has has a function call operator for the arguments `const std::pair<std::string, unsigned>&, const std::pair<std::string, unsigned>&`. As the types do not match, the references cannot be bound to the arguments directly. However, `int` is implicitly convertible to `unsigned` and so given pair is implicitly convertible to the argument pair.

So, you implicitly create a pair of temporary arguments for the comparison. The creation of the temporary strings cause the memory allocation.

---

If you had used `std::equal_to<>` as the comparison operator, it would have not created copies as it deduces the argument types, and thus wouldn't have caused the conversion.

Comment: Equally forcing the type of `key1`, and `key2` to be `key_type`, either by specifying the type rather than relying on `auto` or by adding using `make_pair<key_type>`, will prevent the additional allocation. (In the first case the compiler is smart enough to move the string values when doing the conversion).

Comment: As a C++ newbie I would probably have tried `std::equal_to<decltype(key1)>`, would that have worked? Obviously not as nice as just leaving it out.

Comment: @pipe that would indeed also avoid copying since in that case the argument types would match the type of your pairs.